# Multiple Websites on Apache2

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have my apache configured to have 2 websites setup. I have the following in my apache2.conf

```
Include /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/conf/app.conf
Include /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/conf/app.conf
```

Here are the app.conf for the 2 websites

Website1

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/htdocs
ServerName www.website1.com:80
ServerAlias website1.com
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/log/access.log common

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/htdocs
ServerName website1.uat.com:80
ServerAlias website1.uat.com
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/log/access.log common

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Website 2

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/htdocs
ServerName www.website2.com:80
ServerAlias www.website2.com
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/log/access.log common

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/htdocs
ServerName website2.com:80
ServerAlias website2.com
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/log/access.log common

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.website2.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Im testing these locally so i have my host setup below

```
xx.xxx.xx.xxx www.website1.com
xx.xxx.xx.xxx www.website2.com
```

When i go to www.website2.com, apache2 page pops up
When i go to www.website1.com, apache2 page pops up

When i go to www.website2.com/htdocs, i see the correct website and it works. When i got to www.website1.com/htdocs, i see website2. I dont understand why i am seeing website 2 here.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that you should remove the port :80 from ServerName and also change

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.website1.com/htdocs
ServerName www.website1.com
...
```

Answer (score -1):

As prerik says use "VirtualHost *:80"

Also if it is Apache HTTPD 2.2.x, it needs "NamedVirtualHosts *:80" defined "once" in the config when several virtualhosts are present using the same ip:port scheme, if you don't add this all your requests will land in the first defined virtualhost.